# Commands and packages relationship

Tags: command-line, package-management, bash, kubuntu

I want to find out what commands installing a package makes available in my console.

**For example**: If I want to run the command `quiz` in bash, I have to install a set of packages by asking `apt-get` to install `bsdgames`.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your example, because the question seems quite the opposite to me. Following your example, you would like to know which commands are provided by the package `bsdgames` (that it looks like what you are asking) or which package provides the command `quiz` (that is what you did in your example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search quiz
```

or directly go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and use the feature "Search the contents of packages".

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bsdgames
```

to add the Universe repository, to update the package information and to install `bsdgames`, `quiz` is part of this package.

After that you can run

```
quiz
```

in your terminal.

Why? [That's why](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=quiz&mode=exactfilename&suite=wily&arch=any).